# Python 3 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, scripting, nonetype

```
# import libraries
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#specify the url
html = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND'

# query the website and return the html to thevariable 'page'
page = urlopen(html)

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable 'soup'
data = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

#take out the <div> of name and get its value
name_box = data.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'companyName_99a4824b'})

name = name_box.text.strip() #strip is used to remove starting and trailing
print (name)

# get the index price
price_box = data.find('div', attrs={'class':'priceText_1853e8a5'})
price = price_box.text
print (price)
```

I was following a guide on medium.com [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe) and was having some conflictions due to lacking of knowledge of python and scripting, but I think I have my error at

name = name_box.text

because text is not defined and I am unsure they would like me to define it using the BeautifulSoup library. Any help maybe appreciated. The actual error will be below

```
 RESTART: C:/Users/Parsons PC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/projects/Scripts/S&P 500 website scraper/main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Parsons PC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/projects/Scripts/S&P 500 website scraper/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    name = name_box.text.strip() #strip is used to remove starting and trailing
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: `companyName_99a4824b` is not in the html.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. Or at least there's no heading with that class.

Comment: I don't know where you got `'companyName_99a4824b'` or `priceText_1853e8a5` from but they are not in that tutorial or on the page you are requesting.. using `name` and `price` as per the tutorial returns no problem. `S&P 500 Index
2,663.42`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND does not contain a `<h1>` tag with the class name `companyName_99a4824b`. That's why you are receiving the above error.

In the website. `<h1>` tag look like this,

```
<h1 class="companyName__99a4824b">S&amp;P 500 Index</h1>
```

So to select it, you have to change the class name to `companyName__99a4824b`.

```
name_box = data.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'companyName__99a4824b'})
```

**Finally Result:**

```
# import libraries
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#specify the url
html = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND'

# query the website and return the html to thevariable 'page'
page = urlopen(html)

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable 'soup'
data = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

#take out the <div> of name and get its value
name_box = data.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'companyName__99a4824b'}) #edited companyName_99a4824b -> companyName__99a4824b

name = name_box.text.strip() #strip is used to remove starting and trailing
print (name)

# get the index price
price_box = data.find('div', attrs={'class':'priceText__1853e8a5'}) #edited priceText_1853e8a5 -> priceText__1853e8a5
price = price_box.text
print (price)
```

It would be better if you can also handle this exception, for future class name changes.

Comment: Does it print properly? Because I've read that the website has anti-scraping restrictions. Here's a link for reference: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570401/https-preventing-website-scraping-in-python3